# Metrics one can monitor to OBJECTIVELY decide whether an auditing trigger is "harmful to performance"

Tags: sql-server

I would like to use an update trigger to track changes to a particular table in a SQL Server database (likely 2008R2+, but possibly 2005)

Please note: I do not want to use the built-in change tracking or auditing features of SQL server.

The transactional volume of the table being audited is approximately 15,000 inserts or updates per day, spread very uniformly throughout the day (24 hours), so about 10 transactions per minute.

Based on that, unless my trigger contained an extremely long running procedure (which it won't) I wouldn't expect any performance degradation.  However, the last time we approached the DBA with this issue, our request was declined as "could cause performance issues".

So my question is:  are there some SQL Server performance metrics that could be monitored to absolutely objectively determine whether this trigger (once in place) does or not cause performance degradation?

Example of the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.someTable_AUDIT_TRIGGER
    ON   dbo.someTable
    AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @previousRowXmlValues XML
    DECLARE @currentRowXmlValues XML
    DECLARE @rowCreateSource VARCHAR(100)   
    SET @previousRowXmlValues = (SELECT * FROM DELETED FOR XML AUTO)        
    SET @currentRowXmlValues = (SELECT * FROM INSERTED FOR XML AUTO)        
    SET @rowCreateSource = SYSTEM_USER                                      
    INSERT INTO MetaDataChangeLog(TableName, PreviousRowXmlValues, CurrentRowXmlValues, RowCreateSource)
        VALUES ('someTable',    @PreviousRowXmlValues, @CurrentRowXmlValues, @RowCreateSource)
END
GO
```

Comment: Holy cow.  Inserting an additional audit record per change (15,000 rows/day) is going to cause performance issues?  And for that concern your DBA is holding up implementation of useful business functionality?  I'm sorry.  I have worked in shops that inserted millions of audit rows per day via triggers.  Hardly noticeable.  Time to upgrade from your 286's (or send your DBA to school)

Answer (score 1):

When you say

> Please note: I do not want to use the built-in change tracking or auditing features of SQL server.

I'm assuming that you're referring to sql profiler? If you're allowed to use it then it would seem to answer your question.

So assuming that you're not allowed to use it, the simplest way to test would be to create a procedure that mimic's the inserts, and keeps timestamps of when each operation started and finished (in a separate table). You could then test this trigger on the table (or more likely a test table which is a perfect copy), and see if there's any significant performance hit when the trigger is in place. You can then run queries and compile a statistical report showing your findings.

To summarise, my usual ways of testing performance are:

- Use sql profiler
- Create a clone of the production environment (or just the specific area you're interested in), check timestamps before/after changes.

It may also be prudent to discuss the technical reasoning behind why the dba is reluctant to allow the trigger to be created, so that you can side-step this (provided they're open to any discussion at all of course).

Comment: Sorry, by "I do not want to use the built-in change tracking or auditing features of SQL server" I meant I do not want to use those for the change tracking (aka auditing) itself, I specifically want to use triggers.

Comment: @tbone ok, so it looks like you'll have to go the long way round. You'll just have to examine how long it takes when an insert is done before the triggers are created (ie get a baseline - something to compare to later on), then after the triggers are added examine the performance hit. As I said above, one way of doing this is to simply add timestamp columns for before/after an insert. After the trigger is implemented you can examine the diff of these timestamps and determine if there is a drop in performance (needless to say, there are more efficient ways of doing this).